# Change the default split of vscode

Tags: tabs, visual-studio-code

When I run jupyter interactive windows, vscode code split the screen and put that tab on right side:
[image]

How can I make that kind of tab open on the left side?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`"workbench.editor.openPositioning"`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_tab-ordering) setting:

```json
{
     "workbench.editor.openPositioning": "left"
}
```

Or via the settings menu Editor Management → Open Positioning:

[image: setting]

Comment: Didn't work. This only makes tabs open at left, not that kind of "pop up" like Jupyter interactive

Comment: @pavaj93490 - not sure what you mean then.  It's on the left now correct? Is that not what you asked for?

Comment: No, the jupyter interactive windows still on the right.

Answer (score 0):

It would be the "workbench.editor.openSideBySideDirection" setting, but the only accepted values are `right` and `down`. You could perhaps make a feature request or look for an extension that might have the behaviour you need.

The Open Positioning setting is where new tabs open relative to your current tab. Whereas you are asking about editor groups.